# Printing Hard Copy Images With Python

Tags: python, image, printing

I have seen some topics about this but nothing with a direct answer that I want. I have this script below but it prints out text not images.

```
import os
import tempfile

filename = tempfile.mktemp(".txt")
open (filename , "w").write ("dellow")

os.startfile(filename, "print")
```

Is there anyway to modify this code to print out an image instead of text? Or even create an entirely new script. Just anything that works is fine.

(The image is a simple PNG of my profile picture)

Comment: What exactly is the image supposed to look like? Are you trying to make an image with text on it?

Comment: @BenGrossmann it is just a png of my profile picture but I want to print it using Python because why not